# selenium.common.exceptions.webdriverexception message session not created exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I using selenium (3.4.3) and python3.6 with the Chrome development of the Automation program, I already generate a binary executable program. It works on my PC, but if I put the program in a non python environment it does not work, I see the error messages: the WebDriver still using my pc path, I want know package to the executable program before need the set webdriver? now i using the cx_Freeze-5.0.1,the setup.py config:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "console"

setup(  name = "Cortan",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "my Canto",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},enter code here
    executables = [Executable("Cortan.py`enter code here`", base = base)])
```

The error message text:

```
D:\Cortan>Cortan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\tyb011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
ges\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\tyb011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
ges\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py 

", line 24, in <module>
  File "Cortan.py 

", line 5, in <module>
  File "Cortan.py 

", line 7, in Work
  File "C:\Users\tyb011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
ges\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py 

", line 69, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\tyb011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
ges\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py 

", line 98, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\tyb011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
ges\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py 

", line 188, in start_session
  File "C:\Users\tyb011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
ges\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py 

", line 256, in execute
  File "C:\Users\tyb011\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
ges\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py 

", line 194, in check_response
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exce
ption: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5b
a8),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error message as formatted text.

Comment: ok,I has been Updated.

Comment: Compare the given version from the error message with your Chrome version and update Chrome if needed.

Comment: you mean the Chrome version does not match the cause? but, the error message reference my PC. I mean  the error messages is form the other PC,is not my pc.

Comment: but,i will try update Chrome version,Thank you for your answer.